# android apk into native application

Tags: android, apk

I have some set of APK(andorid) files, I want all those apk to native applications(as like contacts,browser, messaging apps etc) in which file or folder i have to make change in android source code to work all those apk's as like native applications.

thaknks

Answer (score 0):

The steps are..

1. Copy `<AndroidApplication>` to `/<Android_Source>/packages/apps/` folder.
2. Create Android.mk file inside `<AndroidApplication>` directory.
3. Edit `/<Android_Source>/build/target/product/generic.mk` to add line for   `\<AndroidApplication>`

   ```
   PRODUCT_PACKAGES := \
   AccountAndSyncSettings \
   AlarmClock \
   <AndroidApplication> \
   ```
4. Now Compiled source code
5. After compilation is completed you will see `<AndroidApplication>` installed.

**Update:**

For prebuilt `.apk` files..

In **Android.mk** File :

```
LOCAL_MODULE := <YourAppName>
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: More info http://baharkhan.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/how-to-add-own-app-in-source-android/

Comment: I have only apk not source code of those applications. Is it ok for apk with above method???

Comment: Look at my updated answer... And if you find further complex then follow this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/4kRyiFofQkA and this one http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/build_cookbook.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have still doubt. I found in /package/apps/ in all application folders there is Android.mk file. But i have only apk file how can I add Android.mk  and where i put Android.mk file.. ?